Cataloging software on remote computers
I am trying to find an inexpensive way to catalog all of the software installed on our computers.  I would like to be able to do this with PowerShell.
I have tried to use the scripts found on both of these sites (Ref 1 and Ref 2), but when I do I get no results.  Nothing.
After some further research and testing, I was able to catalog the software on one machine, with the script below:
$computers = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\AssetList.csv" -delimiter ","
$array=@()

# Foreach($system in $computers){
    # Get-Service -ComputerName $system -Name RemoteRegistry | Set-Service -StartupType Manual -Passthru | Start-Service
    
    $sysname=hostname
    $InstalledSoftwareKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
    $InstalledSoftware=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$sysname)
    $RegistryKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($InstalledSoftwareKey) 
    $SubKeys=$RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames()

    Foreach ($key in $SubKeys){
        $thisKey=$InstalledSoftwareKey+"\\"+$key
        $thisSubKey=$InstalledSoftware.OpenSubKey($thisKey)
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $sysname
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"))
        $array += $obj
        }
        
    # Get-Service -ComputerName $system -Name RemoteRegistry | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -PassThru | Stop-Service
# }

$array | where { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallLocation | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\CatalogedSoftware.csv"


You'll note that I have commented out a few lines.  When I remove the # marks, I'm back to square one.  No results.  The CSV file is created, but it is absolutely empty.  Can anyone help me figure this out, please.

invoke-command $computers { get-package }

Do I run that separate?  I tried that, but got an error message.
Where in the script do I put that?

Instead of, but it requires remote powershell.

Get-Service does not have a -ComputerName parameter. In order to use Invoke-Command, all of the machines must have PowerShell Remoting. See help Enable-PSRemoting and the 'about' articles in help about_Remote* results. Note also that Get-Service is Windows Only.

@lit powershell 5.1 get-service has a -computername parameter, using rpc

@js2010, then why was your first suggestion to use Invoke-Command? Windows Powershell (5.1-) may have it, but PowerShell Core (6.x+) does not have a -ComputerName parameter on Get-Service.
